# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: date = bytea on date null in native query JPA

Tags: postgresql, localdate, nativequery

I would like to have a native query for Postgresql, however I could not make it work with dates. I can receive date as null, or date as date, so I like to work in both cases:

```
" case when coalesce (?3, null) = ?3 then true " +
" else p.start_date = ?3 end"
```

if ?3 is the third parameter and can be null and it is of type LocalDate

I tried many variations, but could not make it work for both cases, separately it will work:

1. if `coalesce (?3, null) = ?3` for date param null it will work
2. if `p.start_date = ?3` for date param != null it will work

The column in the database is date

Thanks:)

Comment: Did you try `p.start_date = coalesce(?3, p.start_date)` (instead of the `case` expression)

Comment: Just try it I received:

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: COALESCE types bytea and date cannot be matched
  Position: 266

Comment: Then whatever you use to run that statement sends the value as the wrong type. This will most certainly work with plain JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
 case when ?3 <> '' then p.start_date = (cast(?3 as date))
      else 1 = 1 end
```

So, I am passing string parameter and convert it to date, because nothing else worked for me